# Nested UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I am trying to show an alert view inside of another but am having issues.  It shows up briefly...but then disappears on it's own after a second.

Here is the code inside of my first alert view delegate:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    if(buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        Room *room = [[Room alloc] init];
        room = [roomList objectAtIndex:alertView.tag];
        currentRoom = room;
        if([[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text isEqualToString:room.password]){
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"joinRoom" sender:self];
        }
        else{
            alertMessage *message = [[alertMessage alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Invalid password"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [message setStyle];
            [message show];
        }             
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` delegate method instead of the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method. The former is called after the alert is gone. This make more sense when you want to show a second based on the tapped button of the first alert view.

You may wish to have two buttons on the 2nd alert view. One to cancel and one to "Try again". Tapping "try again" would show the password alert again.

Comment: Once again you have helped me out rmaddy.  And thanks for the advice on doing 'Try Again', i'll implement it that way!